# Possible to move Fedora system disk to new computer?

Tags: fedora, migration

I have a **Intel SS4200-E** based Server running `Amahi` (*a Fedora 14 based server package*).

The SS4200-E is stock except a E5200 CPU has replaced the old Atom it comes with. It's loaded with four 2TB discs and a four disk external chassis over eSATA.

Now I have another computer with:

- Q6600 CPU
- Asus P5QL-E Motherboard
- 4x2Gb Corsair DDR2 800MHz

I would rather like not to have to reinstall the entire system, and wonder if it would be possible to move the disks over to the new setup and go. Does the system check all the hardware at start up, or is Fedora very sensitive to hardware changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is just from the side of the OS, you can do that flawlessly, since the kernel is probing the hardware at boot time.

If you have hardware RAID controller setup with these disks, it makes it more complicated from the configuration of the controller standpoint and a little bit from the Fedora standpoint.

My suggestion is that you do a backup of the system files (e.g `/` , `/var` ,`/opt` and so on), then move the disks.

Comment: I have an external RAID cabinet connected via eSATA. So to the OS it only looks like a huge disk. And all partitions are mounted using UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, no problem at all. I just switched a Fedora hard drive to another PC and turned it on. I forgot about the different monitor cable so I pressed and held power button to switch the pc off, got the cable and the PC on again and it's just fine. I didnt check the drivers